# How can I limit a keyword's execution time without failing?

Tags: automated-testing, robotframework, timeout

I am testing an API on a server.  When I close the connection from another external computer to that server it takes some amount of time to complete.  I want to limit the amount of time my test waits for disconnection to complete, but I need to continue with the next test keyword.  Short of cutting my test suite into 2 consecutive test cases, is there some way to tell Robot Framework to allow my keyword t seconds to complete and then to continue along?

I have tried to use a timeout, but that causes the test to fail and I need it to continue.  I am not using Selenium since this is an API test.

Comment: Put some code in order to be more clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Try with this https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error

Comment: I did try both Run Keyword And Ignore Error and Run Keyword And Expect Error.  None of these keywords can prevent a timeout from failing my test case.

Comment: I see, I did not try it before with timeouts. But sadly it does not work then. Maybe you could implement your own timeout mechanism with a python wrapper that won't fail the execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Can use [Wait Until Keyword Succeeds](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds) keyword .
like:

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  5x    4s   click Element   xpath=........
```

Here `5x` is how many times you want to execute your action and `4s` is your time duration, how frequently you want to wait until next try.

Any Many More usage below -

```
*** Settings ***
Library           ExampleLibrary
Library           FailUntilSucceeds.py    3

*** Variables ***
${HELLO}          Used to test that variable name, not value, is shown in arguments


*** Test Cases ***
Fail Because Timeout exceeded
    [Documentation]    FAIL GLOB: Keyword 'Fail Until Retried Often Enough' failed after retrying for 100 milliseconds. The last error was: Still ? times to fail!
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    0.1 seconds    50ms    Fail Until Retried Often Enough

*** Keywords ***    
User Keyword
    ${value} =    Fail Until Retried Often Enough    From User Keyword
    [Return]    ${value}

Wait Until Inside User Keyword
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    3.99 seconds    0.1    Fail Until Retried Often Enough

Timeouted UK with Wait Until KW
    [Arguments]    ${timeout}
    [Timeout]    ${timeout}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    100ms    10ms    Fail    Error in timeouted UK

Access Nonexisting Variable
    Log    ${nonexisting}
    Fail    Should NEVER be executed

Access Initially Nonexisting Variable
    Log    ${created after accessing first time}
    [Teardown]    Set Test Variable    ${created after accessing first time}    created in keyword teardown

Pass with first Try
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    2 minutes    30 seconds    Log    ${HELLO}

Pass With Some Medium Try
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    ${42}    2 milliseconds    Fail Until Retried Often Enough
```

Comment: I did not see Wait Until Keyword Succeeds at first so I did not try it.  I did try just using a loop of defined size (the same sort of strategy) and that worked okay.  Using this keyword works well.  Thanks Kartik.